# NodePacker - Don't understand the question

Tags: java, class, nodes, cluster-computing, cpu

[image: Image for question]

I'm trying to solve this question but I'm having difficulty understanding it. I don't understand what am I supposed to do.

data image

[image]

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I didn't ask for a solution if you can read clearly i said i don't understand it

Comment: I was just trying to be nice, and warn you that there are some things you should do to prevent the closing of this question. You don't care, that's fine.

Comment: Please don't post questions (or any other text) as images

Comment: I understand that you do not actually expect answers to the question in the pictures. I do understand that you want clarifcation of that question. The right source of help for that is the author of the question, probably your teacher. What help do you expect from us? Guesses? Waht if we guess wrong? But if that is what you want please be more specific about which part you do not understand. Ideally explain as much of the question as you can, that will enable us to help with pointing out misunderstandings.